How can I access MPRIS2 metadata from JavaScript?
I want to fetch metadata about currently playing music on Linux music players that support MPRIS2. Python has a library that provides a high-level API for this, but JavaScript doesn't.
I tried searching for a JS MRPIS2 library, but to no avail. I'm currently trying to use the dbus-native package to access it in a lower-level way, but it's proving a bit difficult. This is just something I threw together with some help from AI (although not wholly copied from it):
import * as dbus from "@homebridge/dbus-native";

var sessionBus = dbus.sessionBus();

var player = await sessionBus.getService("org.mpris.MediaPlayer2.AudioTube").getInterface("/org/mpris/MediaPlayer2", "org.mpris.MediaPlayer2.Player");

player.Metadata((err, metadata) => {
    if (err) {
      console.error(err);
    } else {
      console.log(metadata);
    }
});

But it seems like Metadata is not actually a method. I could use some help in reading the metadata. Thanks!

What JavaScript runtime are you using – Node? GJS?

@grawity_u1686 Node.js

Metadata is a property. Some D-Bus libraries have high-level support for properties, but I couldn't find anything like that in this module, so you'll need to read them manually: by calling methods on the org.freedesktop.DBus.Properties interface.
Start with creating a proxy for that interface:
.getInterface("/org/mpris/MediaPlayer2", "org.freedesktop.DBus.Properties");

Access properties using one of the standard methods Get(iface, name) or GetAll(iface):
.Get("org.mpris.MediaPlayer2.Player", "Metadata")
.GetAll("org.mpris.MediaPlayer2.Player")

(Yes, there is also a Set(iface, name, value).)
I assume that in JS they'll need to be formatted as:
obj.Get("org.mpris.MediaPlayer2.Player", "Metadata", (err, metadata) => {
    if (err) {
      console.error(err);
    } else {
      console.log(metadata);
    }
});

or something along those lines.

Alternative: It seems that it is possible to use GObject-based libraries from Node using node-gir. This would give you access to many "native" libraries from GNOME, such as Gio-2.0 which lets you use the GLib2 D-Bus client that most GNOME software uses; as well as Playerctl-2.0 (the library version of the playerctl MPRIS2 client).
(You don't need to be using GNOME for this; the libraries work in any environment.)
I'm not sure how well this works, as GNOME itself prefers its own "GJS" JavaScript runtime that's built entirely around GObject.

Is there a Get method? I can't get it to work (TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'Get')), and the examples in the repo don't seem to use it.
